# How do I write DSLs in Clojure(Script) without parenthesis?

Tags: clojure, racket, dsl, clojurescript

As Clojure(Script) is a Lisp, all examples of DSLs (Domain Specific Languages) in it use parenthesis to encode were expressions begin and end (as Lisp does). However, at least another Lisp dialect ([Racket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racket_(programming_language))), has many examples of "parenthesis less" DSLs ([Creating Languages in Racket](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2068896), [DSL1](http://queue.acm.org/downloads/2011/racket/5-lang/world.rkt), [DSL2](http://www.languageworkbenches.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Ql.pdf)). I can use some ad hoc method to convert:

```
if (a > 10) { print "Ok!" }    ==>    (if (> a 10) (print "Ok!"))
```

I would like to know if there is some best practice guide or library to do these transformations in Clojure. Or maybe someone has ported Racket's functions that do these transformations to Clojure (I am not a Racket user). Can a Racket user point me to some Racket documentation about how it processes such DSLs?

Answer (score 6):

Clojure intentionally did not add user-definable reader-macros. Which are a feature that is used to do top level code transformations. Clojure does include these, they are just not user-definable so there are a fixed number of them.

One example is the #_ reader macro that removes the next expression entirely. (you can stack them)

```
#_#_#_(:println  1) (println 2) (println 3) (println 4)
4
```

What you can do is define tagged literals which solves many of the same problems though they are not really intended for defining external DSLs. Most of the time you would have a top level dsl-start macro and then you don't have to use any `()`s beyond the initial two surrounding the start symbol. With the limitation that what you present in your language must consist of readable expressions (symbolc, maps, vectors, lists, etc.)

```
(with-my-special-language
   if (a > 10) { print "Ok!" }
   if (a > 42) { print "Even Better!" }
)
```

If you really want to avoid exposing the two `()` to the person writing this code you can read that code into a string, add the () your self and then evaluate it. It's very handy having direct access to the reader like this.

Comment: Do you have a pointer to code that can implement this with-my-special-language function/macro?

Comment: It's basically the whole of your program so it would be a bit too big for a Q&A format. The with-my-special-language macro would likely have a signature like `(defmacro with-my-special-language [ & expressions] ... lots of code to parse and make sense of your language ... )`

Comment: Can you put the program in a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) and post the link here?

Comment: I just need the part that convert the non Lisp format to Lisp forms.

Comment: That depends on the design of the "non-lisp" language you want converted into Clojure. There are more options than there are existing non-lisp languages and they all make different design choices. This is really a question of language design and not really something I can answer. Building languages is FUN, go for it!

Comment: I write DSLs in Groovy, but all DSLs, I wrote,  are valid Groovy programs. Clojure programs are represented by Clojure data structures. So, my DSLs cannot be valid Clojure programs. So, the first step, to process these DSLs using Clojure, is to transform them in Clojure data structure (with the minimum changes). There should be, at least, a library that would help me do this.

Comment: To convert one language to another (aka compiling) both languages must be defined. So if you are converting groovy to groovy then the semantics of both the from and two languages (the function argument order and position, the opperators etc) are well defined. If you wanted to convert Groovy syntax to Clojure you would need one compilation function, and if you choose a ruby-like syntax you would need a different function to convert it into a clojure syntax. You need to define your DSL language first, then search for tools and libraries to help you build it.

Answer (score 3):

There is a library called [chiara](https://github.com/jwymanm/chiara) which lets you write Clojure without using parentheses. From the README:

```
(ns my-ns
  (use chiara))

(use-chiara) (chiara

defn foo [x]
  map inc (range x)

def my-list
  foo 10

)
```

It introduces syntax macros which let you do the kind of transformations you're after.